# Dynamic drop down list based on a textfield

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How can I populate the content of a dropdown list dynamically using a text field in ASP.NET?
I do use the Ajax Control Toolkit for all Ajax calls so far.
My Page looks like this:
I have a Modal Popup with a textfield (Autocomplete) and a dropdown list.
The content of the dropdown list should now be populated according to what was selected in the first textfield. The data can be gathered using a webservice or directly in the database. The queries are existing and working.
The issue that I've is, that the `ParentControlID="textField1"` of the `ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown` can't be a text field. 
Is there a better way to solve this issue? Is there even a way without writing the Javascript code by myself?

Comment: Wrap the dropdownlist with an `UpdatePanel` which gets triggered by the some button. The event handler of that button should populate the dropdownlist using the value of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try doing this with Jquery?

Here is a example for the same
http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx

More helpful link
[Dynamically populate the drop-down using jQuery in ASP.Net MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317566/dynamically-populate-the-drop-down-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc3)
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/populate-a-2nd-dropdown-from-the-choice-of-the-first-dropdown